# Oppossing Laser Beams Cause One Beam to Disappear

Tags: experimental-physics, interference, laser-interaction

I posted a video early where I asked the question about opposing laser beams appearing to turn one laser off. Further experiments, however, have demonstrated that it is interference at play not that one laser quits working. Yet, two separate lasers do not create the destructive interference to the extent that my experiment shows. The experiment is two lasers beams facing directly into each other with a 45 degree beam splitter between them. One beam disappears. What happening?
I posted two videos to show what happens
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n66R_OVeiGc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsJ5sMncu_g

Comment: @rob They are similar, but I gathered new info that I felt changed the question from a laser quitting question to an interference question.

Comment: Your next [edit] will put this question into a queue where other site users will decide whether to re-open it; see the [help]. Best wishes!